# Binding multiples Class in Wpf

Tags: vb.net, xaml, binding

I can't link 2 TextBoxes to properties defined in 2 classes.
I tested this simple example
Where is the error, please?

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_multiBinding" xmlns:multipleviewmodel="clr-namespace:WpfApp_multiBinding.MultipleViewModel" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindow}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SP1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ViewModels.ViewMod1.Text1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SP2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModels.ViewMod2.Text2}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainWindow:

```
    Imports WpfApp_multiBinding.MultipleViewModel
    
    Class MainWindow
            Public ViewModels As ViewModels
    
            Sub New()
                InitializeComponent()
    
                ViewModels = New ViewModels
                DataContext = ViewModels
    
                SP1.DataContext = ViewModels.ViewMod1
                SP2.DataContext = ViewModels.ViewMod2
    
                ViewModels.ViewMod1.Text1 = "toto"
                ViewModels.ViewMod2.Text2 = "titi"
            End Sub
        End Class
```

My classes

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
    
    Namespace MultipleViewModel
    
        Public Class ViewModels
            Public ViewMod1 As New ViewModel1
            Public ViewMod2 As New ViewModel2
        End Class
    
        Public Class ViewModel1
    
            Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
            Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    
            Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
                If PropertyChangedEvent IsNot Nothing Then
                    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
                End If
            End Sub
    
            Private Property _Text1 As String
    
            Public Property Text1 As String
                Get
                    Return _Text1
                End Get
                Set(value As String)
                    _Text1 = value
                    OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(Text1)))
                End Set
            End Property
    
        End Class
    Public Class ViewModel2
... idem Class VieModel1 ...
End Class
    End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainWindow's constructor, you are providing a new DataContext to your StackPanels (SP1 and SP2):

```
SP1.DataContext = ViewModels.ViewMod1
SP2.DataContext = ViewModels.ViewMod2
```

Every control in each StackPanel inherits the DataContext of the StackPanel, not the MainWindow's DataContext. Your TextBlock bindings should therefore be adjusted accordingly:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="SP1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SP2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The bindings you currently have are the equivalent to `ViewModels.ViewMod1.ViewModels.ViewMod1.Text1` and `ViewModels.ViewMod2.ViewModels.ViewMod2.Text2`.

Comment: thank you for the solution and especially for explaining my error.
"We always learn from our failures. The important thing is not to always fail."